# WHERE and AND in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause, product

Hi I have a little problem and I can't find the solution. I'm pretty new in MySql.

Let's say I have this Table:

```
 _______________
|prodID| |propID|
|________|______|
|   1    | 2    |
|   1    | 5    |
|   2    | 6    |
|   2    | 7    |
|   3    | 5    |
|   3    | 2    |
|   3    | 9    |
|   4    | 5    |
|   4    | 3    |
|   5    | 2    |
|   5    | 5    |
|________|______|
```

prodID is the Product-ID and propID is the Property-ID.
Now I want to get the Products which for example have the property with propID=2
and the property with propID=5. Where the property in propID=2 is "made from glass" and propID=5 is "safe for children". I want that the products (prodID) I get are both. "Made from glass and safe for children". So the propIDs I would get are 1,3 and 5.

This hasn't worked for me:

```
SELECT prodID FROM table WHERE propID=2 AND propID=5
```

I hope it's clear what I mean and hope someone can help me.

Thanks

Edit:

Table is now changed at prodID=4.
If I would try

```
SELECT prodID FROM table WHERE propID=2 OR propID=5
```

I would get 1,3,4 and 5. But that is not what I wanted.

Comment: I don't get the glass and safe for children part

Comment: `WHERE PROPID=2 OR propID=5`

Comment: @Mr.Alien for example a baby bottle

Comment: @josepchappa those filters are dynamic, right? There might be more than 2 prop to check?

Comment: @deczo Right. There could be more than just 2 properties to check.

Comment: @deczo Thanks. It works so far. I now just need to understand the whole thing. If I have any questions I'll just post it here.

Comment: @josepchappa yeah, check my edit with `distinct` and also try @Alma Do's answer, because it seems to be far better than mine in terms of performance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query you need is:

```
SELECT
  prodID
FROM
  t
WHERE
  propID IN (2,5)
GROUP BY
  prodID
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT propID)=2
```

Also, note, that it's "exactly 2 properties". If you need "at least '2' and '5' in properties" in the result, then change `COUNT(DISTINCT propID)=2` to `COUNT(DISTINCT propID)>=2`. Check this [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33658f/1).

Answer (score 1):

Either with `count` and `having`, or:

```
select * from products 
where (
  select count(distinct propID) from pivot_table where products.ID = pivot_table.prodID 
    and pivot_table.propID IN (2,5)
) = 2
```

`IN(..)` part and `= 2` should be dynamic, according to your needs.

---

`distinct` will solve duplicates issue, however @Alma Do has better solution, that requires simple query without dependant subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

these will not work after your update

*try this
    SELECT DISTINCT prodID FROM table WHERE propID=2 OR propID=5
another way to do it is like this
    SELECT DISTINCT prodID FROM table WHERE propID IN(2,5)*

**EDIT:**

try this instead

```
SELECT prodID FROM table WHERE propID=2 OR propID=5 GROUP BY prodID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT prodID) = 2
```

**NOTE:** if you want to use this query accept AlmaDo's answer as it was proposed before mine.

you could do it with a subquery

```
SELECT prodID FROM (
SELECT prodID, COUNT(DISTINCT prodID) as filter_col FROM myTable
WHERE propID IN(2,5)
GROUP BY prodID
  )t 
WHERE filter_col = 2;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72a7c/1)

Comment: I don't think this is what he need. He wants only the products with both propid =2 and propid =5. Theroblem is that the Table is not normalized.

Comment: @kiks73 did you look at the demo i posted? it does what he asks for

Comment: This has no relation to what OP needs

Comment: it doesn't if you apply his latest changes to your schema

Comment: @AlmaDo would you explain how it is to me? I don't see how or a case when this would error

Comment: Well, I can't say for sure that the query was snatched from another answer, but, obviously, without `DISTINCT` in `COUNT` that will fail on repeated values.

Comment: Ah nice catch... i didn't snatch the query from another one.. if you would like to look though my answers I use this one all of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using OR instead of AND. AND looks for a record where both conditions return true, which in this case is none. OR will return records where either of them are true.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want both conditions to be true `OR` does not work.

A solution is to join the table with itslef and then add a where condition.

```
SELECT t1.prodID
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.prodID = t2.prodID AND t2.propID = 2
WHERE t1.propID = 5
```

But there might be better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This will work too: Using a subquery to filter products with one property, and then filter the ones with also the other property.
[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eda8d/3/0)

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.PRODID 
FROM T INNER JOIN (SELECT PRODID FROM T WHERE PROPID=2) AS TABLE2 
ON T.PRODID = TABLE2.PRODiD
WHERE T.PROPID = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT prodID FROM table WHERE (propID=2 OR propID=5)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why your query works and the OP's doesn't.

Comment: The OP specifically mentions this does not give the desired result.

Comment: Probably his loop is incorrect. Or he didn't make loop or while in results.